# How to create a condition using excel?

Tags: excel

I have a simple question about creating condition in Excel. 
I have a huge amount of data and all I want is create a condition that can filter all the rows.

Example:

```
+---------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| SUM(ratio_order.order_id) | order_year | order_month | total_ratio | completed | canceled | backorder | cod_approved | cod_pending |
+---------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
|                        11 |       2011 |          10 |         100 |         5 |        6 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         2 |       2011 |          11 |           0 |         1 |        1 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         2 |       2011 |          11 |         100 |      NULL |        2 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         1 |       2012 |           1 |          99 |      NULL |        1 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         3 |       2012 |           1 |         100 |      NULL |        3 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         1 |       2012 |           2 |         100 |      NULL |        1 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         1 |       2012 |           3 |          92 |         1 |     NULL |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                        19 |       2012 |           3 |         100 |         6 |       13 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         4 |       2012 |           4 |           0 |         1 |        3 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
|                         1 |       2012 |           4 |           2 |      NULL |        1 |      NULL |         NULL |        NULL |
+---------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

If I have a table like this in Excel. And what i want is to change the color of the row which is not null to color red. The range is order_month,total_ratio and completed.

How can i do that using excel, how can i create a condition for that? Sorry if it is not a programming question. But i hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format, Formatvalues where this formula is true:, enter =$E1<>"NULL" (where E1 represents the location of "Completed"), Format..., select your red formatting, OK, OK. Then go back to Manage Rules..., and adjust Applies to to suit (eg A1:I12), OK.